# Display text on window media player or monitor

Tags: c#, vb.net

I would like to display text like my company name on the window media player. I use DrawString function on Form onPaint event but it is covered by the window media player.
I also use Label control but it display square block on the player control even i set the back color to transparent. I develop KTV system it has two monitor one has form controls and another has player. Please advice me how should I do.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about the windows built-in media player then your going to have to get down and dirty with the Win32 API's, windows hooks, HWND, etc.  You can't just paint a control on the window.  What your talking about is some very low level windows coding.

Take a look at Spy++ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx).  It's a tool from Microsoft that let's you delve into the details of a running application.  It has a component called ManagedSpyLib which wraps the C++ windows libraries in a managed library to make the windows hooks calls easier.  Be ready to learn more about the OS than you ever wanted to know.  :-)